# How can I interpolate 2-D gridded data onto an array of "unstructured" 2-D coordinates with method='cubic'?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, cubic

###### Context:

As interpolation-data (points and values) I have a 2-D 1x1 degree lat-,lon- grid, with a scalar-variable on each gridpoint. Large areas of the grid consists of NaNs (~40%). As coordinates (xi), I have an array of "unstructured" coordinates, all of which are inside of the grids bounds, and very few coordinates (<0.1%) are located near NaNs.

Usually, when linearly interpolating, I use `scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator(points , values, method='linear')` when I interpolate gridded data to unstructured coordinates. Followed by a subsequent nearest neighbor interpolation for the remaining 0.1% where linear interpolation fails near NaNs.

###### Tried:

```
fc = RegularGridInterpolator(points, values, method='cubic', bounds_error=True)
interped_cubic = fc(xi)
```

which raises `"ValueError: Array must not contain infs or nans."`

I have also tried `interp2d`:

```
fc = interp2d(lon0, lat0, data, kind='cubic', bounds_error=True)
interped_cub = fc(lon, lat)
```

which returns interpolated values on a grid of shape (lon.size, lat.size), instead of interpolating onto the coordinates (lon, lat). (see Reproducible example for definition of lon/lat and lon0/lat0)

I have also tried removing the NaNs before interpolating:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interpn
import numpy.ma as ma
mask = np.isnan(data_nan)
lonG,latG = np.meshgrid(lon0,lat0)
lonM = ma.MaskedArray(lonG, mask).compressed()
latM = ma.MaskedArray(latG, mask).compressed()
interped_cub = interpn( (latM, lonM), data_nan[~mask], (lat, lon), method='cubic' )
```

which reduces the grid to a 1-D array with no NaNs. The interpolation returns `ValueError: There are 2 point arrays, but values has 1 dimensions`.

###### Expected:

I expected `f=RegularGridInterpolator(points, values, method='cubic');f(xi)` to return interpolated values on coordinates in non-NaN-areas, and NaN-values on coordinates near or on NaN-areas - The same as what the function returns when using `method='linear'`, only with a different interpolation-method.

###### How can I complete the interpolation?:

Since I am obviously not using the function correctly, can someone explain where my mistake is, and hopefully suggest what I can try, to complete the cubic interpolation onto the coordinates?

###### Reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator, interp2d

### THE FOLLOWING CODEBLOCK RUNS WITHOUT ERROR:
lat0, lon0 = np.linspace(-60, -40, 20), np.linspace(-50, 0.0, 50)
lonG, latG = np.meshgrid(lon0, lat0)
data = np.sin(latG*lonG) # Data has no NaN- areas
lat = np.random.uniform(low=-60, high=-40, size=2000)
lon = np.random.uniform(low=-50, high=0.0, size=2000)
plt.title('2D data, 1x1 grid');plt.pcolormesh(lon0, lat0, data);plt.show()
fl = RegularGridInterpolator((lat0, lon0), data, method='linear', bounds_error=True)
interped_lin = fl((lat, lon))
plt.title('linear interpolation');plt.scatter(lon, lat,c=interped_lin);plt.show()
fc = RegularGridInterpolator((lat0, lon0), data, method='cubic', bounds_error=True)
interped_cub = fc((lat, lon))
plt.title('cubic interpolation');plt.scatter(lon, lat,c=interped_cub);plt.show()


### THE FOLLOWING CODE RAISES ERROR
# Substitute some of the data with NaNs:
data_nan = data.copy()
data_nan[1:8,  5:12] = np.nan
data_nan[2:6, 12:20] = np.nan
plt.title('2D data w/ NaNs, 1x1 grid');plt.pcolormesh(lon0, lat0, data_nan);plt.show()
fl = RegularGridInterpolator((lat0, lon0), data_nan, method='linear', bounds_error=True)
interped_lin = fl((lat, lon))
plt.title('linear interpolation');plt.scatter(lon, lat,c=interped_lin);plt.show()
fc = RegularGridInterpolator((lat0, lon0), data_nan, method='cubic', bounds_error=True)
interped_cub = fc((lat, lon))
plt.title('cubic interpolation');plt.scatter(lon, lat,c=interped_cub);plt.show()


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 27
     25 plt.title('linear interpolation');plt.scatter(lon, lat,c=interped_lin);plt.show()
     26 fc = RegularGridInterpolator((lat0, lon0), data_nan, method='cubic', bounds_error=True)
---> 27 interped_cub = fc((lat, lon))
     28 plt.title('cubic interpolation');plt.scatter(lon, lat,c=interped_cub);plt.show()

File /srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_rgi.py:335, in RegularGridInterpolator.__call__(self, xi, method)
    333     if is_method_changed:
    334         self._validate_grid_dimensions(self.grid, method)
--> 335     result = self._evaluate_spline(self.values.T, xi,
    336                                    self._SPLINE_DEGREE_MAP[method])
    338 if not self.bounds_error and self.fill_value is not None:
    339     result[out_of_bounds] = self.fill_value

File /srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_rgi.py:388, in RegularGridInterpolator._evaluate_spline(self, values, xi, spline_degree)
    381 # Non-stationary procedure: difficult to vectorize this part entirely
    382 # into numpy-level operations. Unfortunately this requires explicit
    383 # looping over each point in xi.
    384 
    385 # can at least vectorize the first pass across all points in the
    386 # last variable of xi.
    387 last_dim = n - 1
--> 388 first_values = self._do_spline_fit(self.grid[last_dim],
    389                                    values,
    390                                    xi[:, last_dim],
    391                                    spline_degree)
    393 # the rest of the dimensions have to be on a per point-in-xi basis
    394 result = np.empty(m, dtype=self.values.dtype)

File /srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_rgi.py:414, in RegularGridInterpolator._do_spline_fit(x, y, pt, k)
    412 @staticmethod
    413 def _do_spline_fit(x, y, pt, k):
--> 414     local_interp = make_interp_spline(x, y, k=k, axis=0)
    415     values = local_interp(pt)
    416     return values

File /srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_bsplines.py:1240, in make_interp_spline(x, y, k, t, bc_type, axis, check_finite)
   1237 axis = normalize_axis_index(axis, y.ndim)
   1239 x = _as_float_array(x, check_finite)
-> 1240 y = _as_float_array(y, check_finite)
   1242 y = np.moveaxis(y, axis, 0)    # now internally interp axis is zero
   1244 # sanity check the input

File /srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_bsplines.py:36, in _as_float_array(x, check_finite)
     34 x = x.astype(dtyp, copy=False)
     35 if check_finite and not np.isfinite(x).all():
---> 36     raise ValueError("Array must not contain infs or nans.")
     37 return x

ValueError: Array must not contain infs or nans.
```

Thanks! And let me know if I can improve my example.

Comment: The ValueError makes sense.  With 'linear' the sphere of influence of the `nan` values is well defined and limited.  With 'cubic' it's broader, and possibly harder the define.  So I'm not surprised that the developers chose to include this constraint.  Check the '[source]' to see when they test this.

Comment: Why not drop the NaN values before interpolating? Is there a context where you want a NaN out of the interpolater?

Comment: @hpaulj That makes sense. However I could not find immediately where in the source it is mentioned.

Comment: @NickODell  See updated "Tried"-section above, where I reduce the grid to a 1-D array with no NaNs. Unfortunately I get a ValueError here too, because the dimension is no longer 2-D. Do you have any other suggestions? 

Ideally I would like the interpolator to behave similarly as with method='linear'. The goal is to interpolate as many values as possible with method='cubic'. Subsequently interpolating the remaining coordinates w/ nearest neighbor.

Comment: The source link on the doc page https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.12.0/scipy/interpolate/_rgi.py#L49-L513

Comment: @hpaulj I see. I guess this is not possible with RegularGridInterpolator then... Please correct me if I am wrong.


Does someone know a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scipy's `RegularGridInterpolator` expects the user to provide data for every point in a regular grid, so leaving out the `NaN` points will result in an error. To interpolate over the `NaN`s you can use an unstructured interpolator, such as [`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata), which allows the user to pass only some of the points (i.e. you can remove the `NaN`s). See some example code below.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

nx = 100
ny = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 10, nx)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, ny)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
n_nan = 1000
non_nan_indices = rng.choice(np.arange(nx*ny), nx*ny - n_nan)

X_nan = X.flatten()[non_nan_indices]
Y_nan = Y.flatten()[non_nan_indices]
Z_nan = np.cos(X_nan)*np.sin(Y_nan)

Z_interp = griddata((X_nan, Y_nan), Z_nan, (X.flatten(), Y.flatten()), method="cubic")
```

`Z_interp` can be reshaped to `(nx, ny)`.

Comment: Thanks alot @Jared, this seems to work on my example!